# phpunit how to solve Error: Using $this when not in object context

Tags: php, phpunit, php-7

I am using php-7 and when running a test I came across with this error.

```
Error: Using $this when not in object context

src/Notification.php:28
tests/NotificationTest.php:10
```

It fails on `$this->log->info(" Message sent ");`

The contents

```
<?php
declare(strict_types=1);
namespace CCP;

use CCP\MyMailer;

class Notification{

    private $log;

    public function __construct(){
        $this->log = $_SESSION['CFG']->log;
    }

    public function sendEmail(string $from, array $to, string $subject, string $body): boolean{
      $mail = new MyMailer;
      $mail->setFrom($from);
      foreach($to as $value){
        $mail->addAddress($value);
      }
      $mail->Subject = $subject;
      $mail->Body =  $body;

      if(!$mail->send())  {
        $this->log->error(" Message could not be sent for ");
        $this->log->error(" Mailer error: ".$mail->ErrorInfo);
        return false;
      } else {
        $this->log->info(" Message sent ");
      }

      return true;
    }
}
?>
```

my test

```
 public function testEmail(){
        $this->assertTrue(Notification::sendEmail("m.w@mail.com",["s.u@mail.com"],"phpunit testting","test true"),"send email");
    }
```

I have read a few articles/answers but they where related to static functions/variables so I don't see how this applies.

Comment: You're calling your method statically.

Comment: You are also missing a closing `}` after the last one, or am i missing one?

Comment: Just checked to be sure, you are **definitely** missing a closing `}`.

Comment: the brace is there, not sure why it didn't copy over

Comment: @Maerlyn how is it meant to be called? its not making much sense to me

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In php, `::` is a token that allows access to static, constant, and overridden properties or methods of a class. So `Notification::sendEmail()` is to call a static method for `Notification` class.

When calling a static methods, no instance of the object is created. So `$this` is not available inside the method declared as static. You need to initialize an object of the `Notification` class then call `sendEmail`:

```
$this->assertTrue((new Notification())->sendEmail("m.w@mail.com",["s.u@mail.com"],"phpunit testting","test true"),"send email");
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is how you call the method in your test. Try this instead:

```
public function testEmail()
{
    $notification = new Notification();

    $this->assertTrue($notification->sendEmail("m.w@mail.com",["s.u@mail.com"],"phpunit testting","test true"),"send email");
}
```

You might also want to read up on the difference of Notification:: vs. $this: https://secure.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.basic.php#language.oop5.basic.class